# Javascript Comparing dropdown lists

Tags: javascript, compare

I'm new to Javascript and I'm having trouble comparing elements from HTML. This is what I have for a function I cannot get the if statement to compare to the word Other which is one of my list items any ideas?

```
function createList(form) {
    var row;    
    var table;  
    var form;   
        
    table = document.getElementById("shoppingList");    
    row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);           
    form = form;
    if (form.elements["storeItems"].value === "Other"){
    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = form.elements["otherItems"].value;}
    else{
        row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = form.elements["storeItems"].value;
    }
    
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = form.elements["funStores"].value;         
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = form.elements["selectColor"].value;               
    row.insertCell(3).innerHTML = form.elements["notes"].value;
    
}
```

My goal is if the list option Other is selected it pulls data from a text Other box instead of the word Other.[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Meta Tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Benoit's living space">
    <meta name="keywords" content="home, funiture, living, space, Benoit">
    <meta name="author" content="Jesse Benoit">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
    <title>Jesse Benoit Homework Chapter 9</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/Homework11.css"> <!-- Import of CSS -->

</head>
<body>
    <h2 class="center">Furniture Shopping List</h2> <!-- Header 2 Centered -->
    <div class="row">
       <p class="center"> <!-- p cenetered with instructions -->
         Time to go shopping! Pick an Item or Items from the list. Pick a Store from the list. Pick a color from the list. Added any extra notes you would like.
       </p> 
        <div class="left">
            <p>
            <!-- Form to gather inputs from the user -->
                <form>
                <label>List of Items</label>
                <select id="storeItems" size="4"></select> <br>
                <label>Other: </label>
                <input type="text" id="otherItems"> <br>
                
                <label>Stores</label>
                <select id="funStores" size="4"></select> <br>
                <label>Other: </label>
                <input type="text" id="otherStores"> <br>
                
                <label>Chose a Color</label> <br>
                <input type="radio" name="selectColor" value="White">White<br>
                <input type="radio" name="selectColor" value="Black">Black<br>
                <input type="radio" name="selectColor" value="Blue">Blue<br>
                <input type="radio" name="selectColor" value="Red">Red<br>
                <input type="radio" name="selectColor" value="OtherColor">Other<br>
                <div id="selectColor"></div>
                
                <label>Notes: </label><br>
                <textarea rows="5" cols="20" id="notes"></textarea><br>
                
                <input type="button" id="submit" value="Create Shopping List" onClick="createList(this.form);"> <!-- Button to create an invitation -->
                <br><br> 
                </form>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <table id="shoppingList">
            <tr>
            <th>Item &nbsp;</th><th>Store &nbsp;</th><th>Color of Item &nbsp;</th><th>Notes &nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
            </table> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <script src="../js/homework11.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>

selectItem();
selectStore();



function selectItem() {
    var myItems = "Couch; Table; Dresser; Chair; Bed; Other" ;
    var itemArray = myItems.split(";");
    var name = 0; 
    var myOption = "";  
    for (var i = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++) { 
        name = itemArray[i];
        myOption = document.createElement("option");
        myOption.name = name;
        myOption.value = name;
        myOption.text = name;
        document.getElementById("storeItems").appendChild(myOption);
    }
}  

function selectStore(){
    var myStore = "Walmart; Target; Wayfair; Other" ; 
    var storeArray = myStore.split(";");
    var name = 0;
    var myOption = "";
    
    for (var i = 0; i < storeArray.length; i++) { 
        name = storeArray[i];
        myOption = document.createElement("option");
        myOption.name = name;
        myOption.value = name;
        myOption.text = name;
        document.getElementById("funStores").appendChild(myOption);
    }
}

function createList(form) {
    var row;    
    var table;  
    var form;   
        
    table = document.getElementById("shoppingList");    
    row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);           
    form = form;
    if (form.elements["storeItems"].value === "Other"){
    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = form.elements["otherItems"].value;}
    else{
        row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = form.elements["storeItems"].value;
    }
    
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = form.elements["funStores"].value;         
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = form.elements["selectColor"].value;               
    row.insertCell(3).innerHTML = form.elements["notes"].value;
    
}
```

Comment: please show the html and css that goes with this

Comment: form is not assigned.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dropdown, you can get the selected value via:

```
let dropdownEl = document.getElementById('storeItems');
console.log(dropdownEl.value);
```

I'm slightly confused with what `form` is - but I'm assuming your dropdown has `id="storeItems"`.

Also, I'm assuming you created the dropdown using the `<select>...</select>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out having the dropdown list as a function was the issue and I needed list my options in the HTML